# Unable to call embedded segue the second time

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicontainerview

I'm trying to build an app similar to Instagram, and I'm stuck at the comments portion. On the left side of the image, it is a VC that has an embedded container view with UITextField and UIButton at the bottom. The container view is embedded with a UITableView that contains all the user profile image, username and the comment itself.

At first load, it can perfectly grab all comments for that post from server side, and displayed perfectly. However, I am unable to call the segue again using `prepareForSegue` to update the UITableView. I'm receiving an error:

> There are unexpected subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed
>   segue has already fired once or a subview was added programmatically?

[image]

Below are my codes:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "getCommentSegue"){
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? CommentsTVC{
            if(!self.commentID.isEmpty){
                destination.UpdateCommentRow(self.profileImage, commentID: self.commentID, comment: self.postComment, dateTimePost: self.dateTime)
                self.commentID = String()
            }
            destination.postID = self.postID
        }
    }
}
```

And after successfully adding a row to my database in the `dispatch_async`:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("getCommentSegue", sender: nil)
```

I've also noticed that when it append new comment to my existing object that stores all the comments, the count for it is 0. I believe it is taking a new reference for the object. Please help!

Comment: if I do not call my container views in this manner, how then I can update the table view with new comments? The "getCommentSegue" is the identifier for this link that I've set in IB.

Comment: @ThePumpingLama The above codes are written inside the left side of VC. While my object to store comments is on the right side in UITableView. Therefore, I need to append the object with new comment. As such, I need to use the left side VC and append the object on the right side UITableViewController. That is why the setup is in this manner.

Comment: You've done all this, just so you can update the table view? Sorry to sound harsh and critical but its the most bonkers things I've ever seen.

Comment: @ChromiumDioxide hmm... How else I can do the things I want to achieve?

Comment: have you embedded navigation controller? are you presnting or pushing another viewcontroller from containerview?

Comment: @Lion at the parent view, it is embedded in a navigation controller. it is using push to another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

embed `navigationcontroller` to container view and then try. It may solve youar problem i think..!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your container view's subviews before you call `performSegue`.

Comment: There is no such function as removeSubviews(). Please look into your answers before posting.

Comment: Thank you, fixed!